In how many ways you can order N (say 20) things, such that one thing A, is always ranked over another (say B).
I am struggling to understand this category of questions, wherein you are asked to rank n things, and you need to find the number of ways you can rank such that one thing, say A is always ranked above another, say B.
Now I understand that the number of ways you can rank all the n things is n!. And I kind of get the idea of symmetry in this question, as well, where, we argue that, out of n! ways, there can only be two things, that A is either ranked above B, or its ranked below B, which makes the number of ways to achieve the desirable result be n!/2.
However, I am trying to do this via the combinatorics approach, not using symmetry. However, I am unable to reach the answer by using that approach. How to calculate this purely using combinatorics?

I don't see the problem with using symmetry.  Of course, you can count the pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ and note that there are $(n-2)!$ ways to order the $n$ things such that $A$ goes to position $i$ and $B$ goes to position $j$.  Perhaps it would help if you described what you mean by "combinatorics"?

The symmetry argument is pure combinatorics. You construct an explicit bijective correspondence between the set of all total orderings with A > B and the set of equivalence classes of orderings (with two orderings equivalent if they differ only by a permutation of {A,B}). Then you note that each equivalence class has exactly two elements.

@lulu By combinatorics, I meant using the nCr and nPr techniques, if that makes sense lol.

@diracdeltafunk While I understand that, I was trying to figure out a way to do this by explicitly using the nCr and/or nPr formuale.

Well, perhaps you prefer my method then.  It's easy enough, though not nearly as clear as the symmetry argument.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose places for $A$ and $B$ so that $A$ is higher. In each of these, the rest can always be arranged $(n-2)!$ ways. So in total the number of arrangements is
$$
\binom{n}{2}(n-2)! = \frac{n!}{2}.
$$
